# Laravel 5.7 - Change .env file location for production

Tags: laravel, dokku, laravel-5.7

I use Dokku to host my **Laravel 5.7** project.

- I have a **.env.production** for production environment.
- I have a **.env.staging** for staging environment.
- I have a **.env.local** for local environment.

I can add Dokku config **APP_ENV=production** on server and I want Laravel know the file to use by **APP_ENV**.

Comment: It's a bad practice to push env files into your repository, you should instead set env variable with `dokku config:set <my_app> VAR=VALUE`

Comment: I want sync envs on Dokku :)

Comment: So, what's the purpose of having them in environment variables ? why not just hard code them into app per env ?
You should take a look too on `dotenv` library https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv